# Pick row with key GROUP_FILENAME and add a new column with column name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
GROUP_FIELD_NAME:BKR_ID
GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:T80
GROUP_FIELD_NAME:GROUP_OFFSET
GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:0
GROUP_FIELD_NAME:GROUP_LENGTH
GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:0
GROUP_FIELD_NAME:FIRM_ID
GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:KIZEM
GROUP_FILENAME:000000018.pdf
GROUP_FIELD_NAME:BKR_ID
GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:T80
GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:P
GROUP_FIELD_NAME:FI_ID
GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:
GROUP_FIELD_NAME:RUN_DTE
GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:20220208
GROUP_FIELD_NAME:FIRM_ID
GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:KIZEM
GROUP_FILENAME:000000019.pdf
```

It has three keys Group field ,group field value and group file name,i want to create a dataframe like this

I am expecting a data frame with three column group_field_name,group_field_value and group_file name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(df['col'].str.extract('GROUP_FILENAME:(.*)|([^:]+):(.*)')
 .set_axis(['GROUP_FILENAME', 'var', 'val'], axis=1)
 .assign(GROUP_FILENAME=lambda d: d['GROUP_FILENAME'].bfill(),
         n=lambda d: d.groupby(['GROUP_FILENAME', 'var']).cumcount()
        )
 .dropna(subset=['var'])
 .pivot(index=['GROUP_FILENAME', 'n'], columns='var', values='val')
 .droplevel(1).rename_axis(columns=None)
 .reset_index('GROUP_FILENAME')
 )
```

Output:

```
  GROUP_FILENAME GROUP_FIELD_NAME GROUP_FIELD_VALUE
0  000000018.pdf           BKR_ID              T80 
1  000000018.pdf     GROUP_OFFSET                 0
2  000000018.pdf     GROUP_LENGTH                 0
3  000000018.pdf          FIRM_ID             KIZEM
4  000000019.pdf           BKR_ID               T80
5  000000019.pdf            FI_ID                 P
6  000000019.pdf          RUN_DTE                  
7  000000019.pdf          FIRM_ID          20220208
8  000000019.pdf              NaN             KIZEM
```

Used input:

```
                              col
0         GROUP_FIELD_NAME:BKR_ID
1          GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:T80 
2   GROUP_FIELD_NAME:GROUP_OFFSET
3             GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:0
4   GROUP_FIELD_NAME:GROUP_LENGTH
5             GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:0
6        GROUP_FIELD_NAME:FIRM_ID
7         GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:KIZEM
8    GROUP_FILENAME:000000018.pdf
9         GROUP_FIELD_NAME:BKR_ID
10          GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:T80
11            GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:P
12         GROUP_FIELD_NAME:FI_ID
13             GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:
14       GROUP_FIELD_NAME:RUN_DTE
15     GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:20220208
16       GROUP_FIELD_NAME:FIRM_ID
17        GROUP_FIELD_VALUE:KIZEM
18   GROUP_FILENAME:000000019.pdf
```

Comment: TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'var' was passed

Comment: I am getting this error.   Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'var' was passed

Comment: @Indrajit this mean you have an older pandas version, see update.